# c++ convert/play videos and images

Tags: c++, winapi, visual-c++

I'm looking for build in library for converting videos/images. i heard something about DirectShow.  Do you know any library you have used to convert videos/images?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For transcoding (converting one video format to another) using Directshow is bit tricky, you want to use Media Foundation for this job.

There is Transcode API available in Media Foundation to achieve this task. This [link](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff485863%28v=VS.85%29.aspx) has more details on Transcode API, tutorials and samples to get you started.

Answer (score 0):

You can use DirectShow for grabbing images from video stream. For it you must [create](http://www.codeproject.com/KB/audio-video/Tanvon_DirectShowFilters.aspx) your own filter node. It is complex task because of filter is COM object that will work within chain (DirectShow filter graph) of other filter nodes - codecs. So after creating you need register your filter in system. As for me i think you can try it because you can use all registered codecs in system and as result get decompressed/final image into your filter. As other solution i think that you can try to use modules from some open source media player. For example try [VideoLAN](http://wiki.videolan.org/Main_Page) but as i know it is big thing and not easy to use.

Good luck!